# Ssh access on aks cluster

Tags: azure, azure-aks

How can i setup persistent ssh access on AKS nodes? I want something similar to launch template/user data from AWS (like having a bash script that is being executed at provision time), not via a DaemonSet.

Comment: Understand this is terrible practice. You should never go outside the control plane to "wing it" over SSH. If you understand that and still want to go for it, see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh.

Answer (score 0):

how do you create your AKS?

If you are using terraform, you can specify a `linux_profile` inside the `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` resource and define a username and ssh key to access your nodes.

With the az cli you can add the `--ssh-key-value` flag.

NOTE: Changing the ssh values forces a new AKS to be created.